# AFrame extend component and override

Tags: aframe

I am trying to extend the a-animation component but override some functionality.

I want to add a state attribute to the parent "el", and only if the parent has that state will a mouseenter event actually trigger the animation.

I am hoping I don't need to re-write or require a Pull request to facilitate this additional functionality as that will slow down testing and usability for me, but I would like to be able to use the main code and only "add or override" functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came here looking for the same answer, "How to extend a component". I wanted to write some custom logic for the [look-controls](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/look-controls.html) component, so I'll share what I learned about extending components.

First of all, I would recommend doing a *copy* on the component to avoid doing any damage to the original component (just in case you are using it elsewhere). I am using Angular, so I have a nice utility for a [deep copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy), but you can use whatever you like. (It looks like A-Frame has some utilities that might do this, but there are no docs as to how to use them: [AFRAME.utils.extend](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/utils.html#aframe-utils-extend-target-source-source), [AFRAME.utils.extendDeep](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/utils.html#aframe-utils-extenddeep-target-source-source)). Copying is up to you.

Anyways, here is how you can *extend* an existing component:

```
// Get a copy of the original component.
var customLookControls = angular.copy(AFRAME.components['look-controls']),
    customLookControlsComponent = customLookControls.Component;

// Add your custom logic to component.
customLookControlsComponent.prototype.myNewMethod = function() { // Something awesome. };
```

Here is how you would *register* it:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('custom-look-controls', customLookControls);
```

And finally, here is how you would *use* it:

```
<a-entity custom-look-controls></a-entity>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Locally I found that creating a new component based off of an existing one, was not working the way I had expected it to. So, in a much simpler way, I found it is pretty easy to extend an existing component:

```js
// Get a reference to the component we want to extend.
var lookControls = AFRAME.components['look-controls'],
    lookControlsComponent = lookControls.Component;


/**
 * Overrides the Touch event handler...
 * @param {!Event} e The touch event object.
 */
lookControlsComponent.prototype.onTouchMove = function(e) {
  // Replace the TouchMove event handler...
};

/**
 * New/custom method...
 */
lookControlsComponent.prototype.somethingNew = function() {
  // My awesome logic here.
};
```

Comment: I don't use angular but so far this is a better answer so I will give you the correct answer so anyone else who might will be able to solve their issue

Comment: I hope it helps, it was a bit of a dig, but outside of the _copy_ part, which is not required, it should suffice. It worked well for my purposes :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to trigger the animation whenever you want.

```
<a-entity id="foo">
  <a-animation begin="bar"></a-animation>
</a-entity>

if (whateverCondition) {
  document.querySelector('#foo').emit('bar');
}
```

Or using the animation component (https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation):

```
<a-entity id="foo" animation="startEvents: bar"></a-entity>

if (whateverCondition) {
  document.querySelector('#foo').emit('bar');
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to have the mouse event stay as mouseenter... I only want more control of the event to require it to be in a certain state. According to the above solution I must add an animation that has its own event and write my own event handler code. I simply want to add a simple if statement before current a-animation code. Just curious if there is an easy way to extend

Comment: When your event has special conditions, it should have a different name. Should not be too much work.